# How can I get my search field to align with the other grid items

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-inputfield

I have a header component with a sub-component search field.

```html
<template>
    <div class="header-grid">
        <div>
            New Opportunitites
        </div>
        <div>
            SUBs
            <lightning-progress-bar value={subProgress}
                                    variant="circular"
                                    size="large">
            </lightning-progress-bar>
        </div>
        <div>
            APPs
            <lightning-progress-bar value={appProgress}
                                    variant="circular"
                                    size="large">
            </lightning-progress-bar>
        </div>
        <div>
            <c-search-field object-api-name={API_NAME}
                            onsearch={onSearch}>
            </c-search-field>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Here's the CSS for the component:

```css
.header-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: 10% 30% 30% 20%;
    grid-gap: 30px;
}
```

The search field sub-component is very simple. Here's its HTML:

```html
<template>
    <lightning-input name="search"
                     type="search"
                     placeholder="Search"
                     onchange={onChange}>
    </lightning-input>
</template>
```

It doesn't currently have any CSS.

When this component gets placed into a larger component, the search field's top doesn't align with the rest of the grid population.

[image: header component]

I'd like the top of the search field to align with the progress bar labels. How can I do this?

Comment: were you able to resolve this one? or lightning-layout didn't cut it?

Comment: also, on an unrelated topic, your stack exchange profile [website link](http://wp.chivalrysoftware.com/resume-for-charles-e-ross) returns 404

Answer (score 2):

if you wrap your elements with [lightning layout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-layout) and layout items, you can use the vertical-align property to center your items, otherwise, you can check other [CSS properties](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/) to achieve the same.

after taking a closer look, the issue with using "lightning-input" is that there is a label element in the DOM (above the input) which causes this misalignment issue (1 of the main reasons I avoid namespace lightning components)
So, you can either add a margin top or padding to push your element down a bit.